# Convert XLS to CSV without login

Tags: excel, powershell, etl

I have a PowerShell script to convert my XLS files to CSV every week. The script works well, but I have to run it manually as a login user to trigger an Excel instance in the background on my computer (as shown below).

```
$Excel_app = new-object -ComObject Excel.Application
```

I was wondering if anyone could give me some advice on how to automate this process, for example, if even my computer is logged out, the converting would still happen etc.

I am also open to rewrite the script in other languages, but I am not sure if others would also require a login user to open Excel etc.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You may be able to do it with this NuGet package: https://www.nuget.org/packages/DocumentFormat.OpenXml/

Comment: The Task Scheduler can run scripts without an interactive user being logged in.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Task Scheduler to run the task without a user logged in, but [you may have to configure the DCOM permissions](https://superuser.com/questions/579900/why-cant-excel-open-a-file-when-run-from-task-scheduler) to get it to work non-interactively.

A better solution might be to use the [`ImportExcel` PowerShell module](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/ImportExcel/), which is based on [EPPlus](https://github.com/JanKallman/EPPlus) so it doesn't need Excel at all.  That should just work from Task Scheduler since there's no COM Objects at all, but there's a small chance of incompatibility if you're doing something particularly unusual with your Excel documents.  It also has the advantage of not requiring Excel to be installed.